# Codeigniter trim not working in database class

Tags: database, codeigniter

I need to do trim before inserting into database. I am using codeigniter . Now if i have to do trim before inserting , then i have to make code change across project . So i thought to do trim before insertion operation executed by codeigniter .

In system/database/drivers/mysql/mysql_driver.php 
in the _insert function i introduced a forloop to trim the data in array . The code is as follows .

```
function _insert($table, $keys, $values){
  $arr = array();
  foreach($values as $k => $v)
    $arr[$k] = trim($v);
  return "INSERT INTO ".$table." (".implode(', ', $keys).") VALUES (".implode(', ', $arr).")";
}
```

Any guidance is appreciated . After inserting if i see the value database it is not trimmed. The same while i could see in the log file.

Comment: It will better not to change the core class of the Codeigniter. Instead create a new class that extends the database class. You can then override the function accordingly.

Comment: most of the code is easy to update, however the DB classes are not designed like the core/libraries/helpers. Unless i missed something when i was using it.

Comment: this is bad practice i advise not to hack directly to CI's core, no one will answer hacking onto the core ,when you can extend it or use hooks. or format and clean you're data before using the insert method.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I could get this done from hooks class as supported by codeigniter.

Firstly enable hooks in application/config.php

Second application/config/hooks.php have added the following code .

```
$hook['pre_controller'] = array(
                            'function' => 'MyTrimer',
                            'filename' => 'utilities.php',
                            'filepath' => 'hooks'
                            );
```

Finally added the below code in , hooks/utilities.php

```
function MyTrimer(){
  if(count($_POST) > 0 ){
    foreach($_POST as $k => $v){
      if(!is_array($_POST[$k])){ 
        $_POST[$k]=trim($_POST[$k]);
      }   
    }   
  }
}
```

Comment: This is best solution as we do not need to change for each post variable.

Answer (score 0):

After posting in controller you could write trime before each post
example code:

```
$this->load->model('test_model');
$form_data = array(
          'fname'   =>trim($this->input->post('first_name')),
          'lname'   =>trim($this->input->post('last_name')),
          'position'=>trim($this->input->post('position'))
           );
$this->test_model->insert('test_table',$form_data);
```

Comment: I could do that. But at lot of places , have insert scripts. SO cannot change across project. I have get this done by using hooks.

Answer (score 0):

After posting in controller you could write escape before each post 
example code:

```
$this->db->escape($this->input->post('first_name'));
```